Powerpivot with slicer on two tables
Trying to learn PowerPivot and slicers using two simple tables.
Titles:

Media:

The tables are linked by ID

I created a pivot table listing the Titles > title field and a slicer based on the Media > media field:

The slicer has no effect on the pivot table results. Thought this was a basic use case but not sure what I'm missing, appreciate any help.

The arrow is from title table to media table. I think that will allow you filter the media table by selecting the data in title table.
You can try this in Power BI. Power BI allows you to change the arrow direction to both.
